# Как обработать POST запрос через admin django

Tags: django, django-admin

Есть две модели:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    count_choice= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Вид из admin django

[image: Вид из admin django]
Мне необходимо, что бы **при создании** в колонку count_choice модели question записывалось кол-во choice, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В admin.py

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        super(QuestionAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        choices_count = Choice.objects.filter(question=obj).count()
        obj.count_choice=choices_count
        obj.save()
```

Обратите внимание, что в этом варианте переопределяется метод QuestionAdmin, а не ChoiceAdmin. И срабатывает он при любых операциях, не только создании. Можно добавить проверку аргумента change, но тогда count_choice будет иметь неверное значение при удалении вариантов.

Comment: Я добавил, как вы написали, при создании и нажатии кнопки Save в admin panel, поле count_choice не заполняется. Что-то необходимо редактировать в вашем коде?

Comment: И правда, инлайны сохраняются по-другому. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: super(PollAdmin, self) заменить на super(QuestionAdmin, self) и filter(poll=obj) поменять на filter(question=obj) и конкретно для моего случая работает. Спасибо!

Comment: Приверял на одном из своих проектов :)